# Angularjs replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to replace my underscore with a line break using AngularJS. The problem is after replacing it with a `br` it became messed up. Please help.

[image]

[image]

```
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="table">
<thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Home</th>
    <th>Office</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="list in lists">
        <td>{{list.name}}</td>
       <td>{{list.mobile.replace('_', '<br/>')}}</td>
       <td>{{list.home}}</td>
       <td>{{list.office}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.lists = <?php echo json_encode( $this->lists->fetchtable() ); ?>;
});
</script>
```

This is how my php echo looks like from right-click, view source:

```
$scope.lists = [{"id":"1","name":"Alan","mobile":"0124445555","home":"0355552222","office":"0399997777"},{"id":"2","name":"Bobby","mobile":"0135558888","home":"0377778888","office":"0311112222"},{"id":"3","name":"Cindy","mobile":"018777666_0189995555","home":"","office":"0399997777"},{"id":"4","name":"David","mobile":"0174442222","home":"067778888_0355551111","office":""},{"id":"5","name":"Eddy","mobile":"0156662222","home":"0755554444","office":"068888555_0399995555"},{"id":"6","name":"Faith","mobile":"0128882222","home":"","office":""}];
```

Comment: I don't think you can use replace in angular expression syntax. You could split the content of mobile in js code before you render.

Comment: Please don't use profanity when posting on Stack Overflow.